# Why can't I change my background to a solid colour

Tags: 18.04

I want a solid colour for my wallpaper. Everything is selectable and I choose a colour but, there is no change.
Here is my settings window:

[image: Settings window]

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of which flavor of which operating system are you using.

Comment: Choose the one that says "No desktop background".  It is possibly the first one in the list.

Comment: user68186 - Ubuntu Studio 18.04 64-bit

Comment: cup - there is no "No desktop background" option.