# Ubuntu 20.04 change background to solid colour

Tags: 20.04, desktop-background

There was an option to change background to solid color. However, I notice that that option is no longer there.

The only options available are to use existing image or to add picture.

Was this setting moved to somewhere else?

[image]

Here are some of the option available in the previous version

Ubuntu Studio 18.04 64-bit

[Why can't I change my background to a solid colour](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217547/why-cant-i-change-my-background-to-a-solid-colour)

Look at the `solid colour` settings there

[image]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1169145/739431

Comment: The absence of this feature is craziness.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Newer versions of Ubuntu Desktop have removed the capability to set the background to a solid color. You may run the following command in a terminal window to accomplish this task:

To clear the current image setting:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri none
```

To set the primary color (the first color in a gradient or the solid color):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color '#000000'
```

Reference: https://www.fcpace.com/node/55

Comment: Another reason to love linux.

Comment: A slightly more elegant way to remove the picture might be to set `picture-options` to `none`.  (Although I suspect Gnome is much smarter than to try and load a picture from an empty string.)

Comment: This will probably pollute the logs with an error where it does not find an expected bitmap background image.

Comment: Works on 21.04!

Answer (score 19):

So building on Sabrina's answer to create a plain colour gradient background without messing around making an image the following works:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'none'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color '#004000'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background secondary-color '#306030'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background color-shading-type 'vertical'
```

The primary colour will be the top (or left if you go for horizontal instead of vertical) and the secondary colour will be the bottom (or right).

Comment: Honestly, best answer here.  It is BS that they've changed (removed) so many items on Ubuntu 20.004.  I was lastly using 16.04.10 and have just switched as of today, and want to have ZERO images on this machine (in order to run a special program I need to run) and I come looking on how to NOT have an image as a background, and the FIRST and highest rated answer tells you "how to draw a different image" (that looks like a gradient), if you don't like the ones they have provided by default.

Comment: Like seriously, WTF.  I honestly do not even understand how it even got a single up-vote, let alone  the 52 it currently has.  
Back to the issue at hand, IF ANYONE can link me to a page where they are discussing the removing of colors, and forcing of images for backgrounds, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @PyTis so just use the "picture-options none" line in the above. and maybe also set a primary-color if you don't want plain black.

Comment: This method also works in 22.04 - well done

Answer (score 15):

For people using the dark theme on recent releases of Ubuntu, there is another `gsettings` value that may need to be set.

1. First, clear the background image:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark none
   ```
2. Set the background color:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color '#000000'
   ```

Just as with Sabrina's answer, this will show a nice black background again.

(Must be a new feature, as I already did the changes before and it worked. After an update, I got a background image again...)

Comment: works for 22.04 LTS

Answer (score 3):

You can also find these settings using `dconf Editor`

1. Install dconf Editor `apt-get install dconf-editor`
2. Paste the path `/org/gnome/desktop/background` into the URL edit box
3. Click on *picture-uri* and set the path to blank
4. Modify your color

[image: dconf Editor desktop background settings]

Answer (score 0):

I used my iPhone with the flash turned off to take a picture of "solidblack" (no shortage of black plastic in my house), then imported and applied the photo to my 20.04 desktop.  This worked fine.
I also did some testing with an upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 where the desktop was already set to solid black.  The upgrade preserved that setting.

Comment: Good resourcefulness.  But instead of taking and importing a photo, you could create one cleanly from the terminal, e.g: `sudo apt install imagemagick`; `convert -size 1920x1080 canvas:black black.png` (see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504522/create-blank-image-in-imagemagick)

Answer (score 0):

### Solid and Gradient Wallpaper

I use Open Office Draw to create my gradient backgrounds, then export the .odg file as a .jpg. I select this .jpg when I Change Background. I increase the size of the image a little when exporting it. You are welcome to my image, (attached), if you like. In my opinion 20.04 has the worst screen images of any Ubuntu to date.

[image]

[image]

Comment: For a simple gradient, you may well find that PNG is both better quality *and* smaller than the equivalent JPEG.

Comment: Like seriously, WTF. I honestly do not even understand how it even got a single up-vote. I come looking on how to NOT have an image as a background, and the FIRST answer tells you "how to draw agradient-like different image," if you don't like the ones they have provided by default.  The question ASKED was how to NOT use an image, and how to use a color, and you answer with, here is a way to use an image?
Back to the issue at hand, IF ANYONE can link me to a page where they are discussing the removing of colors, and forcing of images for backgrounds, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry it took too long to answer this.

Find Desktop | Background | Style and select None.

You're welcome.

Comment: This option doesn't exist on Ubuntu 20.04 with the GNOME desktop environment. Do you perhaps use another desktop environment or another version of Ubuntu?